# How to express that ABC and DEF are co-planar?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Is there a neater way to express that the Cartesian points A,B,C are co-planar with the points D,E,F? ABC and DEF are triangles. With co-planar, I mean that the triangles ABC and DEF lie in the same plane, i.e. that the six points lie in the same plane. My current expression feels too verbose and obtuse:

$\exists\alpha : (A-C)\times(B-C) = \alpha (D-F)\times(E-F)$

It's for an algorithm description in a paper. I think the best way would be to write in text that "A,B,C are co-planar with D,E,F", but my supervisor insists that I additionally express it in equations (along with other, simpler-to-express conditions).

Comment: I think your condition doesn't say that $A, B, C, D, E, F$ are coplanar, but rather that planes $ABC$ and $DEF$ are parallel.

Comment: @timon92 Oops, you're right! Thank you, I'm happy you noticed and pointed it out. The condition that I intended is that the triangles ABC and DEF lie in the same plane (i.e. A,B,C,D,E,F are coplanar).

Answer (score 1):

If $\begin{vmatrix}
A_x&A_y&A_z&1\\
B_x&B_y&B_z&1\\
C_x&C_y&C_z&1\\
D_x&D_y&D_z&1
\end{vmatrix}=0,$
then the four points $\{A,B,C,D\}\text{ are coplanar.}$
You must perform this test twice more -- replacing $D\text{ with }E\text{, then with }F.$

If any of the three tests fail, then the whole she-bang fails.

If it is necessary to do this procedure repeatedly for points $\{A,B,C\}$
and for differing sets of other points, compute the following constants,
which can be used repeatedly with the other point sets:

$U_x=-\begin{vmatrix}A_y&A_z&1\\B_y&B_z&1\\C_y&C_z&1\end{vmatrix}$

$U_y=\begin{vmatrix}A_x&A_z&1\\B_x&B_z&1\\C_x&C_z&1\end{vmatrix}$

$U_z=-\begin{vmatrix}A_x&A_y&1\\B_x&B_y&1\\C_x&C_y&1\end{vmatrix}$

$U_1=\begin{vmatrix}A_x&A_y&A_z\\B_x&B_y&B_z\\C_x&C_y&C_z\end{vmatrix}$

Then, say, for point P, the coplanarity test boils down to whether or not
$U_x·P_x+U_y·P_y+U_z·P_z+U_1=0$